# Calculate how good prediction is

Tags: statistics

I wrote a method which does some predictions and I want to calculate how good predictions are.
So I have a column with predicted values and a column with actual values.

What is the best statistical method should I use to calculate how good predictions are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several. First define the error associated with a prediction $i$ as $e_i = A_i - F_i$ (the difference between the $i$-th actual value and the $i$-th forecasted value). Suppose you have $n$ observations in your column. The following measures are commonly used:

**1. The mean absolute deviation (MAD)**
$$ \text{MAD} = \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{|e_i|}{n}$$

**2. The root mean squared error (RMSE)**
$$\text{RMSE} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^2}{n}}$$

**3. The mean absolute percentage error (MAPE)**
$$ \text{MAPE} = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{|e_i|}{A_i}$$

All of them are useful in their own way, as they convey different information about the magnitude of the "average" error. 2 and 3 seem to be used quite a bit in practical application (e.g. the Netflix prize used 2 to measure the forecasting quality).